# Jquery Mobile with Master page ( browser url not changing on navigation) sharepoint

Tags: jquery

i have one master page (mymaster.master) and 2 normal pages **MobileA.aspx and MobileB.aspx**. currently i want to redirect to MobileB.aspx on click of a button in MobileA.aspx , i want to make use of the jquery mobile Ajax call for loading pages , so i have not used rel="external"/ data-ajax="false".

once i make a response.redirect("/mobileB.aspx") it loads properly but only issue is Browser url is still **/MobileA.aspx** . after reading some blogs people who faced same issue they added data-url="/MobileB.aspx", in MobileB.aspx and it works fine .

in my case, i have a master page where i have added data-role ="page" to main div , now the mobileB.aspx loads inside the inner div with data-role="content" . so even if i add the data-url attribute it just ignores it .

any help is appreciated how can i make the browser url to change to the MobileB.aspx .